# Use script in all spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

I'm in the process of completely switching from excel to google spreadsheets. I'm writing a set of simple scripts that will help me be productive. Is there any way to make it so that these scripts are inherited by all google spreadsheets that I open (new + existing) from my google account? I know I can publish an add-in, but short of this...

In other words, when I open a new google spreadsheet I'd love to have my custom menus & functions automatically be available.

Thanks!

Comment: The way to have it is by creating a library out of your 'base' code and use it on new sheets or publish an Add-on.

Answer (score 3):

[Add-ons for Google Sheets, Docs, and Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/) provide this capability.