# Created a script which I want to be available for all documents

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I've created a fairly simple script which finds English and replaces it with Spanish words.

```
function translatesp() {
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
  .getBody();

body.replaceText('Master Change Log', 'Historial de Cambios');
body.replaceText('Prepared for:', 'Preparado para:'); 
body.replaceText('Git Reference', 'Referencia Git');

}
```

But the function is only available on the document in which I created the code. How can I make this available in all instances of Google Docs? Sorry if this has been asked before, I did search but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Create an add-on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use script in all spreadsheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25221994/use-script-in-all-spreadsheets)

Comment: The answer of the above linked question apply to Google Documents, Forms, Slides and Sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways I know of:

1. Publish it to the Google Docs Template Gallery. If you are a G Suite user, you can limit its visibility to your domain. Otherwise, the template is available for anyone to  use. Using this approach, you will have to select the template in a new doc to use the function.
2. Publish it as a Docs Add-on. There's a [bit of rigmarole](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish) required to publish, but once done, you can [enable it from the Add-ons menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs#add-ons_for_google_docs) in any doc. Once again, if you are a G Suite user, you can limit the visibility of the Add-on to people within your organization. If you expect that you will add more custom functions in the future, this is a much more streamlined approach.

Comment: The question is about Google Documents, not Google Sheets, but the your recommendations could be extended to Documents, Forms and Slides. Consider to add your improved answer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/25221994/1595451

Comment: @Rubén thanks - I edited my answer for Docs. I'll have a look at the other question.

Comment: I only just saw this, but I will try it when I'm back in work next week and provide feedback. Thanks.

Comment: I've just gotten round to looking at this. I think Nico's option 1 will be the better option for me. One question though, which applies for both ways I think: After publishing, is it possible to make changes to my script within the published version or would I need to keep re-publishing?

Comment: @ChrisA I'm not sure about the public gallery, but in a G Suite domain-specific gallery you can choose to publish a copy or publish the original. If you publish the original, any changes you make will be saved to the template. I would think it would be the same for the public gallery, but I don't know.