# Google Spreadsheet Script Executable On Any New Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to create a script in Google Drive that you can call or execute on any opened spreadsheets without having to keep installing the script on each opened spreadsheet?

I have data I upload to Google drive from time to time and these data comes from suppliers. I upload them to GDrive and then I do all sorts of stuffs like moving columns or adding new columns etc. I want to create a script to automate this but the problem is the script I'm creating will be attached to that spreadsheet I'm using and any new uploaded spreadsheet means I have to copy the script over to that new spreadsheet so I can run it there again.

This is kinda hard to explain but is it possible to create a script, save it on GDrive and whenever I am viewing a new spreadsheet I can run that script to do things to that spreadsheet I'm currently viewing?

Comment: This has been asked before. If you don't use an add on / standalone script, then you simply must authorize each new project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deny granting permissions in my own google scripts everytime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50811046/deny-granting-permissions-in-my-own-google-scripts-everytime)

Comment: @tehhowch Unfortunately that was not the answer I was looking for.

Comment: You described an add on (use a single script in any of my sheets to modify it). So you either write one and publish it (privately is fine), or you deal with authorizing copies / stubs of a library.