# Manually/Programmatically Adding Scopes

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions, scopes

I have a Google Form that acts as a Parent/Template with Google Apps Scripts tied along with it. Whenever I make a copy of the Google Form, the Google Apps Scripts are copied along with it but the scopes have to be reviewed each time. Is there a way to manually add scopes so I don't have to review permissions every time?

Comment: You can publish your Apps Script as add-on, then you will be able to give permission for it just once, see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/

Comment: Each copy is a new script project. Google doesn't let **anyone** run an arbitrary, unapproved script. Thus, you must authorize each copy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deny granting permissions in my own google scripts everytime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50811046/deny-granting-permissions-in-my-own-google-scripts-everytime)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google Apps Script REST API's [projects.updateContent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/updateContent) method to update the existing manifest file with the required scopes.

Note that -

> One of the files is a script manifest; it must be named "appsscript", must have type of JSON, and include the manifest configurations for the project.

Hope this helps.